# How to arrange multiple charts from Google Charts in a grid in a local web page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to display multiple charts in a 3x3 grid in a local web page using Google Charts.  The following example uses the UiApp to create the layout:

```
var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                   .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                   .add(ageFilter).add(genderFilter)
                   .setSpacing(70))
         .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                   .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
                   .setSpacing(10)));

uiApp.add(dashboard);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard

However, it seems the UiApp library is only available to applications hosted on Google services. I would like to use something similar on a local web page. What options are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing every chart in an html table provides a quick solution:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="GoogleChartID"></div></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed an Apps Script UI in an external website that is not hosted on Google Sites. There is currently an [open issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852) for this. Please star the issue to register your interest.